Roots of polynomials defined by the Syracuse (Collatz) sequence
I'm a french graduate student, and I stumbled on a problem which seems to surpass my current abilities...
My goal was to study polynomials defined by the Syracuse sequence (or Collatz sequence). By that, I mean to take an integer, apply the Syracuse algorithm, and stop when I get to 1 (as far as I know, there is no proof that we will always get to 1, and that's the point of the Collatz conjecture, but considering there are quite a few sequences ending in the 4,2,1 loop, I can define my polynomials). Once this is done, I've got a finite sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \{1,...,n\}}$ and I define the polynomial $PSY(a_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a_{k+1}X^k}$. (PSY stands for "Polynome de SYracuse", SYracuse Polynomial.)
I used Sage to plot these polynomial and look at their roots. It looked like every time I took an odd number as the starting point of my sequence, I got a real root somewhere between $-0.5$ and $-0.3$, that I'll note $\delta_{a_1}$ with $a_1$ the starting number. Putting bigger numbers as $a_1$, I saw that all the roots seemed to get closer to the unit circle except $\delta_{a_1}$, always real, between $-0.5$ and $-0.3$. (I'll put images at the end of the post to illustrate)


After that, I tried to "reverse" my polynomial, meaning that, with $(a_k)_{k \in \{1,...,n\}}$, I define the polynomial $psy(a_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a_{n-k}X^k}$. Then, there were 2 complex roots (and there conjugate), which I'll call $\alpha_{a_1}$ and $\beta_{a_1}$, which seemed not to get closer to the unit circle (contrarily to the others).


So, I wanted to study these polynomials, and more specificly the sequences $(\delta_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(\gamma_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and $(\beta_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, but immediately failed. My teachers told me the subject was interesting, but that they had no idea how to study it, and that it could be worth sharing it on a maths platform (so here I am !).
(My bet is that these sequences converge, but it is purely instinctive, lacking every kind of objectivity and pragmatism  ^^')
I hope this problem finds you well !

If you seek collaboration then you should also share your code. Also you should ask a precise question.

I used Jupyter to work on that, here is the link : https://cocalc.com/share/public_paths/5d4afa5e981ddc7758a9f3a13eb814716087ee41        my question is wether or not the sequences of roots are well-defined and what is their behaviour (do they converge ?) (I should precise that as a student, I didnt do much code, so it might not be the most efficient)

You can divide all factors of your polynom by $a_1$, you will have something more easy to visualize.
I will consider only $a_1$ relatively big (say greater than 100), so we can consider that $3x+1$ is very close to $3x$
You play with $a_1$ odd. So $a_2= 3 a_1+1$ and $a_3=\frac{a_2}{2}$;
Your polynom is always something like $1+ 3.0001 x + 1.5001 x^2 +$...
you can consider the following terms, you will have to analyze different configurations.
But we are sure that the factors do not increase very fast. In the worst cases ($a_1=511$ or $1023$ for example), we may reach $a_{11}$ close to $7.6$ ; for $x$ in the range $]-0.5, -0.3[$ , $a_{11} x^{10}$ is lower than $0.0073$ ; your polynom is $1+ 3.0001 x + 1.5001 x^2 +$ other terms that are very small for numbers in $]-0.5, -0.3[$ ; This polynom is negative for $x=-0.5$, and positive for $x=-0.3$ ; so there is a real root between $-0.5$ and $-0.3$
There are many approximations in this answer, but I think it 'prooves' that there is always a real root in this range.

How do you define $a^j,$ ($j=1,2,...$)? If they are real, then why do you have up–down asymmetry in your illustrations?

@JohnBentin the $a_j$ are defined by the Syracuse algorithm. You start by chosing a number $a_1$. If it is even, you divide it by $2$ to get $a_2$. If it is odd, you multiply it by $3$ and add $1$. Then you repeat the algorithm to get $a_3$ and the other terms. The illustrations represent the image of the polynomial defined by the sequence. The $a_j$ are all natural numbers, but a polynomial in $\mathbb{N}[X]$ can be seen in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ to get all its roots (that's what the illustrations represent).

@Lourrran thank you ! It is an interesting insight (eventhough I am not too comfortable with the approximations, but the idea looks reassuring !). So with this in mind, the sequences of roots $(\delta_j)$ seems well-defined ! But I do not have any idea on how to study such a sequence...

I think that John Bentin was totally aware of this. Yours illustrations use colors. What is the meaning of each color ? I have some ideas, but I prefer your real-insight than my wrong-hypothesis. And the question from John Bentin was : how can you obtain different colors for $a+ib$ and $a-ib$, with polynoms in $R[X]$ ?

About illustrations, I suppose that each illustration is obtained with one specific$a_1$ ; it would be fine to say which value $a_1$ was used for each illustration.

Last comment for today, I am interested with sequence $\delta_{a_1}$ only ; can you share some  values , $a_1$ and $\delta_{a_1}$ ; If you work with modulo $1024$ for example (or any number $2^p$) , I am pretty sure that $\delta_{ n+1024k}$ depends mainly on $n$, and $k$ has a very very small impact on the result. So the sequence $\delta_{a_1}$ is more or less periodic with period $1024$.

Nice observation!!!
